# Texto debajo de checkbox

Tags: javascript, html5

Estoy desarrollando la siguiente interfaz
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

pero como podrán notar, el texto se posiciona en la parte de abajo de cada checkbox, entonces es algo raro ya que por default debería ponerse a un lado, esto lo estoy pintando desde javascript, pero el resultado final en el navegador es el siguiente código HTML:

```
<div class="span10" id="divContent2"><br>
                <div id="DivCheckPregunta" style="width: 100%; text-align: right;"></div>
                    <div id="txtPregunta" style="color: black; padding-right: 30px; padding-left: 30px; font-size: 18px; font-weight: bold;">
                      <p><span size="5" color="#444444">Tres valores que debe estar configurado para permitir que un PC para conectarse con una red? (Elija 3)</span></p></div><br><br><br>                    
                <div id="divRespuestasSugeridad_Pregunta" style="color: black; padding-left: 30px;">
                    <div style="padding-right: 30px; padding-bottom: 20px;" onchange="AplicacionEncuestas.ClicEnRespuestaMultipleVariasRespuestas(472, 153)">
<input name="rbRespuesta" id="rbRespuesta472" type="checkbox"> Dirección IP
                    </div>

                    <div style="padding-right: 30px; padding-bottom: 20px;" onchange="AplicacionEncuestas.ClicEnRespuestaMultipleVariasRespuestas(473, 153)">
<input name="rbRespuesta" id="rbRespuesta473" type="checkbox"> Dirección de&nbsp;MAC
                    </div>

                    <div style="padding-right: 30px; padding-bottom: 20px;" onchange="AplicacionEncuestas.ClicEnRespuestaMultipleVariasRespuestas(474, 153)">
<input name="rbRespuesta" id="rbRespuesta474" type="checkbox"> Máscara
                    </div>

                    <div style="padding-right: 30px; padding-bottom: 20px;" onchange="AplicacionEncuestas.ClicEnRespuestaMultipleVariasRespuestas(475, 153)">
<input name="rbRespuesta" id="rbRespuesta475" type="checkbox"> Puerta de Enlace
                    </div>
                    <div style="padding-right: 30px; padding-bottom: 20px;" onchange="AplicacionEncuestas.ClicEnRespuestaMultipleVariasRespuestas(476, 153)">
    <input name="rbRespuesta" id="rbRespuesta476" type="checkbox"> Direcciones de correo</div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

De hecho lo he probado en editores de código en línea y se ajusta correctamente
[Codepen: Formulario](https://codepen.io/Chekame/pen/RVdRxp)

Habria alguna manera de ajustarlos con puro css?

Answer (score 0):

Puedes solucionarlo encerrando esos textos en párrafos y luego quitándoles el margin por defecto, en este caso lo he dejado en 0px, pero puedes ponerle el margin que te acomode más:

aquí el [codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/rmRMBV).

Y el código:

```
<div class="span10" id="divContent2"><br>
                <div id="DivCheckPregunta" style="width: 100%; text-align: right;"></div>
                    <div id="txtPregunta" style="color: black; padding-right: 30px; padding-left: 30px; font-size: 18px; font-weight: bold;">
                      <p><span size="5" color="#444444">Tres valores que debe estar configurado para permitir que un PC para conectarse con una red? (Elija 3)</span></p></div><br><br><br>                    
                <div id="divRespuestasSugeridad_Pregunta" style="color: black; padding-left: 30px;">
                    <div style="padding-right: 30px; padding-bottom: 20px;" onchange="AplicacionEncuestas.ClicEnRespuestaMultipleVariasRespuestas(472, 153)">
<input name="rbRespuesta" id="rbRespuesta472" type="checkbox"> <p style="margin-top:0px">Dirección IP</p>
                    </div>

                    <div style="padding-right: 30px; padding-bottom: 20px;" onchange="AplicacionEncuestas.ClicEnRespuestaMultipleVariasRespuestas(473, 153)">
<input name="rbRespuesta" id="rbRespuesta473" type="checkbox"> <p style="margin-top:0px">Dirección de&nbsp;MAC</p>
                    </div>

                    <div style="padding-right: 30px; padding-bottom: 20px;" onchange="AplicacionEncuestas.ClicEnRespuestaMultipleVariasRespuestas(474, 153)">
<input name="rbRespuesta" id="rbRespuesta474" type="checkbox"> <p style="margin-top:0px">Máscara</p>
                    </div>

                    <div style="padding-right: 30px; padding-bottom: 20px;" onchange="AplicacionEncuestas.ClicEnRespuestaMultipleVariasRespuestas(475, 153)">
<input name="rbRespuesta" id="rbRespuesta475" type="checkbox"> <p style="margin-top:0px">Puerta de Enlace</p>
                    </div>
                    <div style="padding-right: 30px; padding-bottom: 20px;" onchange="AplicacionEncuestas.ClicEnRespuestaMultipleVariasRespuestas(476, 153)">
    <input name="rbRespuesta" id="rbRespuesta476" type="checkbox"> <p style="margin-top:0px">Direcciones de correo</p></div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Por cierto, creo que el texto instructivo debería decir:

Marque tres valores que deben estar configurados para permitir que un PC se conecte a una red.

Espero haberte ayudado.

Answer (score 0):

No necesitas nada de CSS en principio para ajustar el texto, puedes hacerlo con una etiqueta label en cada input.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
 <input id="prueba" name="direccion" type="checkbox">
  <label for="prueba">Direccion ip</label>
</body>
</html>
```